# How to select the string html using Regex?

Tags: regex

I tried to select `&quot;` only but unable to select the correct output

Input:

```
&quot;V&amp;M&quot; Test
```

Regex:

```
(&nbsp;|&quot;|&amp;|[\w&#0-9;]+|.)
```

Ouput: I need:

```
Match 1
1.  &quot;
Match 2
1.  V&amp;M
Match 3
1.   &quot;  
Match 4
1.  Test
```

Comment: You may use `&quot;|(?:(?!&quot;)\S)+`

Answer (score 3):

Try this:

```
&quot;|.*?(?=&quot;|$)
```

It matches either `&quot;` or anything else until next `&quot;` or end of string.

Demo: https://regex101.com/r/82TOog/1

Comment: Unroll it as [`&quot;|[^&\s]*(?:&(?!quot;)[^&\s]*)*`](https://regex101.com/r/fpmnHN/1), you will get a performance boost.

Answer (score 0):

Here is a suggestion:

```
(&nbsp;)|(&quot;)|(\w&amp;\w)|[\w]+
```

#### [Try it on Regex101](https://regex101.com/r/etNGwW/3)

---

Here is also a more generic way that matchs anything between `&` and `;`:

```
(&[\w]+;)|[\w]+
```

#### [Try it on Regex101](https://regex101.com/r/etNGwW/2)